# JavaFX TableColumn with nested Bean

Tags: javafx, tableview, javabeans

i need to show on a `TableView` a column that is a nested bean like this:

```
public class A_Bean {
    private ObjectProperty<BigDecimal>  id;
    private B_Bean qwerty;
}


public class B_Bean {
    private ObjectProperty<BigDecimal>  id;
    private StringProperty  qwerty_B;
}
```

All the bean class has the get, set and property method. My problem is that `A_Bean` has a variable of `B_Bean` type, and i don't know how to tell to the `tableColumn` that it must display the `qwerty_B` field of `B_Bean` and not the pointer to the `qwerty` variable of `A_Bean`.

```
@FXML
private TableView<A_Bean> myTable;
@FXML
private TableColumn<A_Bean, BigDecimal> idColumn;
@FXML
private TableColumn<A_Bean, B_Bean> qwertyColumn;

.....

@FXML
private void initialize() {
idColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().idProperty() );
qwertyColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().qwertyProperty() );
.....
}

public void setMainApp(MainApp mainApp) {
    this.mainApp = mainApp;
    myTable.setItems(mainApp.getA_BeanData());
}
```

If if run my code i'll see on the `tableColumn` something like `xx.B_Bean@1234dasf23`

I need to tell to the `tableColumn` that it must fetch the `qwerty_B` field from the `A_Bean`. How can i do that?

Comment: I would have expected to see `xx.B_Bean@hashcode`, not `xx.A_Bean@hashcode`... are you sure that's what you're seeing?

Comment: yeah, i've done a typo, it's  `xx.B_Bean@1234dasf23`. Any suggestion for solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a cell factory to tell the cell how to display the `B_Bean` it contains as its value:

```
qwertyColumn.setCellFactory(tc -> new TableCell<A_Bean, B_Bean>() {
    @Override
    protected void updateItem(B_Bean item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        setText(empty ? null : item.getQwerty_B());
    }
});
```

Comment: Great! it'w working!Just remember to import `javafx.scene.control.TableCell`. Thanks!